# inverse of market basket analysis with R

Tags: r, analysis, cross-validation, apriori, data-science

I want to do an analysis on :what item didnt go well together in Market basket analyis . Basically finding out which item together didnt go out of the queue . I have a situation , where an record ( containing 13 attribute/column )is incomplete because of various combinations of attributes  . 
  for ex : a1,a2 .... a13 . 
All the above attributes may or maynot have values . But any attribute not having values will make the record to be incomplete

with this situation , I need to see, which combination of incomplete records is mostly occuring in my recordsets. Knowing this pattern will help my team prioritize the records which needs most attention .
   I see that Apriori algorithm takes only values whcih are available , but I need to analyse the combination that is not occuring . I am sure this problem should have been solved in the past , but I dont see any hints in the forum . 
   Does anyone have any experience of such kind? Or do you suggest any other Algorithm that i should use ? I am using R for this analyis. And the total records :218k

Comment: If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical analysis method for your data, then you should post your question to [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. This is not really a specific programming question. The fact that you want to use R is irrelevant for choosing the proper way to analyze your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I grasp your stated situation right, you'd like to get of a dataset, where an item of a case either has a value or doesn't have a value, association rules to those cases which has at least one item without value and then only to these items, which has no values. For this purpose is the Apriori algorithm just fine. And you even don't need to invert it. The solution lies here within the formatting of the dataset: Just get rid of the items with values and give the items without values a value like the name of the regarding item, e.g. a12. Then your dataset only contains cases with at least one item without value and items without values, plus those items can be identified by their values, i.e. their names. Now it's possible for the Apriori algorithm to extract of the formatted dataset the frequent itemsets and subsequently association rules. Concerning if you should use another algorithm to extract association rules: Yes. Use the FP-Growth. It is a way faster than the Apriori algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , that answer helped .I need to analyse all null items in each transaction and I need to see which combination of null has most occurence from all the transactions. 
    I tried replacing all my null values with constants . Did some tweaks in the apriori algorithm to get the those constants as rhs . But I didnt understand,how FP growth algorithm could help on this?can you explain .

Comment: The Apriori and FP-Growth algorithm share the identical aim: Extracting frequent itemsets and association rules. The older Apriori algorithm is just slower in doing so. It needs to scan multiple times the dataset in its processing, whereas the FP-Growth just needs a total of two scans. (Keywords: candidate generation and FP-Growth tree)